# node.js optional chaining if modifying my request object

Tags: javascript

Okay, so this one is throwing me for a loop. Any help?

For starters it's a next.js middleware using next-connect. The goal is very simple, find an authorization token to be processed later by a JWT parser middleware.

Consider the code below. The goal here is to pull the value of the bearer token if it exists. Otherwise, the value for req.jwt should be undefined. I'm using optional chaining in case req.headers is undefined and/or req.headers.authorization is undefined.

All of this code does what I would expect. The header is present and includes the string "Bearer some_bearer_token_value" and the value in the token constant is "some_bearer_token_value"

BUT after that line of code is executed, the req IncomingMessage object is no longer an object, but is instead the unsplit value of req.headers.authorization.

```
export default async (req, res, next) => {
  // Look for a bearer token.
  const token = req.headers?.authorization?.split(/Bearer /i)[1];
  req.jwt = token;
  next();
}
```

Why would the code above modify the value in req?

This code works perfectly fine in the node.js CLI runtime if req is a simple object that looks something like this:

```
let req = {
  headers: {
    authorization: "Bearer some_bearer_token_value"
  }
};
```

Thanks, friends!

Comment: How do you check the value of `req`?

Comment: In my VS Code debugger

Comment: Do not add SOLVED to the title. When the system allows it, you may click the checkmark next to your own answer to properly close this question.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I can chalk this down as a debugger issue. It changes in debugger to a string, but if I console.log(typeof req) it shows up as "object"

Just a weird VS Code debugger thing.

Which explains why it worked when I tried the same thing in the command line node.js runtime.